# filter duplicated rows that has nonmatching variable values .in R

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter some rows that have duplicated and I need the non-matching duplicates to filter.

Here is the sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(
         id =  c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
         cat = c(3,3,4,5,2,2,1,5),
  actual.cat = c(3,4,4,5,2,1,1,7))

> df
  id cat    actual.cat
1  1   3          3
2  2   3          4
3  2   4          4
4  3   5          5
5  4   2          2
6  5   2          1
7  5   1          1
8  6   5          7
```

So, each id has `cat` and `actual.cat`. When there is a duplicated `id`, I need to filter the nonmatching row.

Here what I need.

```
> df
  id cat     actual.cat
  1   3          3
  2   3          4
  3   5          5
  4   2          2
  5   2          1
  6   5          7
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by operation and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     filter(n() > 1 & cat != actual.cat|n() == 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [6]
#     id   cat actual.cat
#  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1     3          3
#2     2     3          4
#3     3     5          5
#4     4     2          2
#5     5     2          1
#6     6     5          7
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df, id %in% names(which(table(id) > 1)) & 
     cat != actual.cat| id %in% names(which(table(id) == 1)))
```

Comment: worked great thanks for your time. `dplyr` is always a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `subset` with `ave` to select rows in each `id` where number of rows in each group is 1 or `cat` is not equal to `actual.cat`.

```
subset(df, ave(cat != actual.cat, id, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1 | x))

#  id cat actual.cat
#1  1   3          3
#2  2   3          4
#4  3   5          5
#5  4   2          2
#6  5   2          1
#8  6   5          7
```

You can also write this logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N == 1 | cat != actual.cat], id]
```